# Save Logs on Heroku with Node

Tags: node.js, heroku, logging, winston

I'm trying to find a way to store logs so that they can be seen in my website.

I have a website hosted in Heroku, where I use a package like Winston to save logs to a .log file. The problem occurs when using this system in Heroku, as when the dyno restarts every day, the log file gets deleted and a brand new .log file is created.

What would be the best way to store all these logs without them being lost on a dyno restart?

PD: I don't monitor logs but I just want a simple way of storing logs to be viewed by people in my website. Right now it's done by reading the .log file.

Comment: You can redirect logs into a database directly with winston like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56801367/4388775). Moreover you will need an api to query this data if you want to see it from the client.

Comment: From what I have read, storing logs to a database is not a very good idea. Do you think it may be better to store a .log file with AWS static?

Comment: It depends on the volume and use cases. Elasticsearch could be a good option. I'm not sure you want to deal with files if you want to query logs from the past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One interesting option could be using [Papertrail](https://www.papertrail.com/): there is a free plan and with it you get a REST API to query the logs (you can then customise what users see/download).

Papertrail has [Heroku integration](https://www.papertrail.com/solution/heroku-logging/) so pushing the logs from your application should be pretty simple. You can then query/export what your need implementing access via the REST API.

Heroku has also a [Papertrail add-on](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/papertrail) which I think it is the same concept as above but running on Heroku cloud.

Obviously the free plan has a short data retention, you will need to see if this works for you.

Comment: I understand how you would save the logs to Papertrail from Heroku, but how would I be able to fetch all those logs in a node website so I can use them there?

Comment: Papertrail provides a REST API (https://documentation.solarwinds.com/en/Success_Center/papertrail/Content/kb/how-it-works/http-api.htm?cshid=pt-how-it-works-http-api), using this you are able to query and fetch the  events. Your web site (application) will need to use this API and run the queries

Comment: I have tested the API and it works but Heroku logs are pushing me to not do it this way, as their logs are messy and some of them are even empty. I'm only interested in the app logs and not the route logs. I think I may have to create a database table and upload logs there. What do you think?

Comment: Nice to hear it works. I would filter the logs when querying with the REST API (maybe your app logs have a specific format or a label) so you only get what you want. Using Papertrail avoids the need to use your own DB (so no extra cost or development), but it is still an option.